# angular 5 production build taking a lot of time and resources

Tags: angular, compilation, production, angular5

I just upgrade my project from angular 4 to five. 
Testing the deployment process I face this issue: 
the compilation process never ends: 
I m  running this command:

```
ng build --prod
```

my ng version is the following:
Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 8.2.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

```
@angular/cli: 1.6.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.25
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.48
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.4
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.13
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

the node process is taking a lot of memory. this is the output of my monitor

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS           %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS    COW    
9575  node         143.4 28:24.52 11/1  1    48    1691M+ 0B     0B     29574 29574 running  *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  908303+   352
    29574  node         0.0   00:00.60 11    1    51    32M    0B     0B     29574 29518 sleeping *0[1]  0.00000 0.00000    501  15062     342
```

the ng build command just shows

```
11% building modules 11/23 modules 12 active ...orgchart/dist/css/jquery.orgchart.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append.
 92% chunk asset optimization
```

any idea how to solve this issue? and finish my compilation process as usual ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have same issue on large project and in the end it usually crashes.
Managed to fix it with adding more resources to the node.

```
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod",
```

npm run build

Comment: where i can add this Line, and after that can i run this command 'ng build -prod -optimizer'?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `@angular/cli` to version `1.7.0` or greater, preferably `6.0.0` (which is at the time of this post on "beta")

That is `@angular/cli: 1.6.4` to `@angular/cli: ^1.7.0` or `@angular/cli: ^6.0.0-beta.2`